# WebTestClient is null when autowired in a @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test, webtestclient

My Spring Boot application runs on version 2.4.2. I'm trying to setup an integration test for a user registration. This test class extends from the `AbstractIntegrationTest` which defines some static setup.

When starting the test, `webTestClient` is `null`. I tried to add `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient` but the issue remains.

Do you have any idea what could be missing here?

**RegistrationIT.java**

```java
public class RegistrationIT extends AbstractIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void shouldRegisterNewUser() throws JSONException {
        String requestBody;  // some JSON

        webTestClient
                .post()
                .uri("/api/user")
                .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(requestBody))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

**AbstractIntegrationTest.java**

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("integration-test")
@Testcontainers
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest {

    private static final String MARIADB_IMAGE_NAME = "mariadb:10.4.16";
    private static final String MARIADB_DATABASE_NAME = "test_db";
    private static final String MARIADB_USERNAME = "test_user";
    private static final String MARIADB_PASSWORD = "test_pass";

    static final MariaDBContainer mariaDBContainer = (MariaDBContainer) new MariaDBContainer(MARIADB_IMAGE_NAME)
            .withDatabaseName(MARIADB_DATABASE_NAME)
            .withUsername(MARIADB_USERNAME)
            .withPassword(MARIADB_PASSWORD)
            .withReuse(true);

    static {
        mariaDBContainer.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", mariaDBContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", mariaDBContainer::getUsername);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", mariaDBContainer::getPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is your class RegistrationIT abstract? Maybe this could be the reason?

Comment: Sorry, this was a copy-paste mistake. I updates the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging, I discovered that I used the `@Test` annotation from JUnit 4 instead of JUnit 5. After having correct the `import` statement, the test runs successfully.